# Modify hosts file Android

Tags: java, android, permissions, hosts

I'm trying to modify the hosts file in Java Android to dynamically add new hosts. Is there any way to do this ?

I tried to follow chatgpt response but it doesn't work

Comment: If Android even *has* a `hosts` file, it will not be editable by ordinary apps, for security reasons.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.